# Date.getTime() giving a time of 2000 1st Jan

Tags: java, windows, windows-7

I have observed this unusual behavior in a few laptops.  I had some issue running in the application we developed.  On debugging it we found that new Date.getTime() is pointing to an old date . After that we tried to run a small program on those machines. The following is the code we used.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args)  {
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime());
        ConcurrentHashMap chm = new ConcurrentHashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            chm.put(i, new Date().getTime());

                if (Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(chm.get(i))) < 1332334082344l) {
                    System.out
                            .println(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(chm.get(i))));
                }



        }

        System.out.println("dONE "+chm.size()+" "+chm.get(1000));
    }
}
```

The output is something like "946684800617" if a few case.  When we saw the date it points to Jan 1st 2000 and some milliseconds.  This is not happening in all the laptops.

Wanted to know why this is happening so that we can work over it.

PS : We are using windows 7 (pro),Lenovo ThinkPad L420

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Do the laptops on which the problem occurs have a different version than other systems?

Comment: they use java 1.6.0.22 .. all of them use the same java

Comment: And whats the system time on the laptops?

Comment: Wild guess: Could it be that some other software (for example time synchronization tool, or something else that affects time) is resetting time to "factory settings" for a brief moment, and Java happen to catch that moment sometimes and report invalid date? I'd start from running same tests with other language, best idea would be C++.

Comment: @Max : will try doing that and post .. but i dont think it is that because it happens any time of the day and the synchronization tool are at a specific time.. And as far as I am aware there is nothing installed in those system except windows 7, .net frame work, java and tom cat .. thats it

Comment: Hmmm, `Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(chm.get(i)))` is the same as `(Long) chm.get(i)` ??

Comment: And `System.out.println(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(chm.get(i))));` is the same as `System.out.println(chm.get(i));`

Comment: @PeterLawrey : yes they are same.. tried that as well

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question a such but your code is so complex it could have unintended consequences.  Can you try running this which does the same thing?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int length = 100000;
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        long[] times = new long[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            times[i] = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (times[i] < 1332334082344L)
                System.out.println(times[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Done " + times.length + " " + times[1000]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this would take some time .. will let you know once i check it Peter

Comment: This is to make sure its not something subtle in the way CHM, Date parsing, TimeZones etc works.